# Keras: What is the output of predict_generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, keras

The Keras documentation says it returns "A Numpy array of predictions."
Using it on 496 image examples with 4 classes, I get a 4-dimensional array
(496, 4, 4, 512). What are the other 2 dimensions?
Eventually, I would like to have an array of X (examples) and an array of Y (labels).

```
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
top_model_weights_path = 'bottleneck_fc_model.h5'
train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
nb_train_samples = 496
nb_validation_samples = 213
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16
number_of_classes = 3
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

# build the VGG16 network (exclude last layer)
model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

# generate training data from image files
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)

# predict bottleneck features on training data
bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
    train_generator, nb_train_samples // batch_size)
print(bottleneck_features_train.shape)

train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'rb'))
print(train_data.shape)
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant parts of the code, especially the ones describing your model?

Comment: @Mike - code added

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is extracting the bottleneck features from the images you're feeding to the model.
The shape (496, 4, 4, 512) you're obtaining is (*n_samples, feature_height, feature_width, feature:channels*)
You took out the dense layers of the model by passing

```
include_top=False
```

to explain graphically, you passed the samples through this model

[image: VGG16 Model]

**without** the last 4 layers. (*you have different height and width because your staring image is 150x150 and not 224x224 like in standard VGG16*)

What you obtain is not the prediction of the classes but a synthetic representation of the important features of the images.

To obtain what you seem to need you can modify the code like this

```
model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
model = Dense(512, activation='relu')(model) #512 is a parameter you can tweak, the higher, the more complex the model
model = Dense(number_of_classes, activation='softmax')(model)
```

Now you would call model.fit(X,Y) on the samples you're using to train the model giving it as X the 496 sample images and as Y the ground truth label you prepared.

After the training you can use model.predict to predict the classes you need.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I generate matrices X and Y for model.fit(X,Y) from train_data?

Comment: Since you seem to be working with a generator you can use model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=100, epochs=100)